Read delta lake table data residing in ADLS Gen2 storage
We have a UX scenario on our web page to display delta table preview data. We would like to show top 100 records from Delta table(Delta Lake). Table files are stored on ADLS gen2 storage account. Has anyone implemented above requirement. we can't take dependency on external service like synapse job, databricks, HDinsight to read data. Our application is in C# & hosted in service fabric. We have angular JS for front end which interact with Service Fabrics hosted application. We would like retrieve top 100 records by using C# Microsoft.Data.DeltaLake library
